# Change collapsible sidebar to fixed

Tags: reactjs, react-sidebar

I have a react website with a collapsible sidebar, my problem is i want the sidebar to be permanent instead of clicking button it stays permanently open. I am confused on how to do that so can anyone help.

Code :

```
const Sidebar = () => {
const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
<Nav>

<button onClick={showSidebar}>Sidebar</button>
</Nav>
    <SidebarNav sidebar={sidebar}>
    <SidebarWrap>
{SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
        return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />;
        })}
</SidebarWrap>
    </SidebarNav>
</IconContext.Provider>
</>
```

Comment: Share the full code pls!

Comment: it's too big for stack here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0HRi5tZUuxGNZ5_-A04-jwCfrOx6u32/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok did you log `sidebar` to the console and saw what the value is ?
if it changes (true/false) then just share the `SidebarNav` component please

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UrwxtM3ENU0feEZ8WOV6Fof94RG9o8fs/view?usp=sharing. Nothing is displayed in the console

Comment: please share `<SidebarNav sidebar={sidebar}>` component not `<Sidebar>`, where you send `sidebar={sidebar}` state to i mean.
But since you don't see any log so it's logical that it doesn't work man!

Comment: i followed this tutorial - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-responsive-sidebar-with-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245966/discussion-between-siddhant-kumar-and-shadi-amr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you wanna it to be always open , now it's just a css change :

```
const SidebarNav = styled.nav`
  ... // Old
  left: ${({ sidebar }) => (sidebar ? "0" : "-100%")};

    // New
  left: 0;
  ...
`;
```

And then you don't need the **sidebar** state and the relevant setter at all!

Comment: If possible can you help with another question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877519/upload-image-to-firebase-storage-and-upload-url-to-firestore-simultaneously-in-r